# how to read an id of a tag in html using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

```
$handle = fopen("exercise/Exercise.php", "r");    //file to be read
$file = fread($handle ,8192);
print("Size of the file: ".strlen($file)."\n");
$html =$file;
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->getElementsByTagName("font")->item(0);
fclose($handle);
```

but this code is not working I am getting an error

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <head> tag in Entity, line: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\csstutorial.php on line 17

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 34 in C:\xampp\htdocs\csstutorial.php on line 17
```

I don't know where i went wrong?? should I use `$dom->load($html);` this instead.

code for Exercise.php :

```html
<html>
<title>Exercise </title>
    <head >
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <font  font face='Calibri'>
        <div id="1">
        <?php
            echo "<p> <B>Question 1) </B>Go to this address "
        ?>
        <a href="https://loans.icicibank.com/personal-loan.html?WT.mc_id=PL_Applyonline&_ga=1.98179290.431324016.1423809984" target='_blank' style="text-decoration: none">ICICI Personal Loans</a>
        <?php
            echo nl2br("and apply for loan as 4 cases  Type of employment:
                a.) Salaried
                b.) Salaried Employed Professional 
                With the help of")
        ?>
        <a href="Salary.xlsx" download style="text-decoration: none">Excel sheet</a>
        <?php </font> ?>
        </p></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to get the id of `<div>` tags. whats the best way to go about it.

Comment: The <title> tag must be inside your <head> tag.

Comment: The first step would be to ensure you're providing [valid code](http://validator.w3.org/check) to DOMDocument (hint: you aren't).

Comment: @ChristianVarga thank you for sarcastic and unhelpful comment.

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt thank you nice catch. now do you have any suggestion how can extract the div id

Comment: @qtpseleniumSupport Your code is invalid. I provided a link to the w3c validator, so you can check your code for issues and validate it. How exactly is that unhelpful? Invalid code causes all sorts of issues, especially with DOM parsers, so it's a great place to start.

Comment: @ChristianVarga oh I am sorry I didn't see the link was also present. ok now i understand your comment thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this $doc->getElementById('div-id')->item(0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this $ret = $html->find('div[id=foo]');

// foo is the div id.

If you want to read inner dom element you can use

$html->find("#div1", 0)->children(1)->children(1)->children(2)->id;

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$doc->getElementsByTagName('div')[0]->id
```

0 is the index number for your div among total divs in your page.

Answer (score 0):

To get id attributes from div tags you can use this code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('exercise/Exercise.php');
$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($divs as $div) {    
    if($div->hasAttribute('id')){
        echo $div->attributes->getNamedItem('id')->nodeValue . '<br>';
    }    
}
```

To avoid warning messages fix your Exercise.php:

```
<html>    
    <head >
        <title>Exercise </title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <font  font face='Calibri'>
        <div id="1">
            <?php
            echo "<p> <B>Question 1) </B>Go to this address "
            ?>
            <a href="https://loans.icicibank.com/personal-loan.html?WT.mc_id=PL_Applyonline&amp;_ga=1.98179290.431324016.1423809984" target='_blank' style="text-decoration: none">ICICI Personal Loans</a>
            <?php
            echo nl2br("and apply for loan as 4 cases  Type of employment:
                a.) Salaried
                b.) Salaried Employed Professional 
                With the help of")
            ?>
            <a href="Salary.xlsx" download style="text-decoration: none">Excel sheet</a>            
        </div>
        </font>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use regular expressions to match the ID attribute in a string:

```
<?php
$str =<<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="5"></div>
</body>
</html>
HTML; // This line must be without spaces to the start

$matches = array();
$result = preg_match_all('/<div[^>]+id=\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]*>/', 
    $str, $matches);

if($result === 1) {
    var_dump($matches);
    // result: $matches[1][0] == 5
    /* ***************************
      array (size=2)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string '<div id="5">' (length=12)
          1 => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string '5' (length=1)

    *************************** */
}
```

Comment: RegEx should not be used to parse (x)HTML. OP is using the correct aproach with DOMDocument

Comment: DOMDocument should be used with valid XML. With invalid HTML can be used RelaxNG or parse the string with a regular expression